# How to use Firebase Email login with a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My question about title. Here my login code. When i use like this, i got "Cannot resolve method addOnCompleteListener...." . Android studio fix that by casting to Executor but when it casted i got Exception "Fragment cannot cast to Executor" so i can't cast Executor. How can i solve this problem ?

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View v;
Button btnLogin;
TextView btnLostPw,btnRegister;
EditText txMail,txPass;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

     btnLogin = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.login_btn_login);
     btnLostPw =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.login_btn_lost_pw);
     btnRegister=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.login_btn_register);
     txMail=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
     txPass=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.login_pass);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLostPw.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



    if(v.getId() == R.id.login_btn_lost_pw)
    {
        //Password Recovery
    }

    else if(v.getId() == R.id.login_btn_register)
    {
        //Register
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.login_btn_login)
    {
        LoginUser(txMail.getText().toString(),txPass.getText().toString());
    }
}

private void LoginUser(String mail, final String password) {

    try {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment mFrag = new NextFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFrag);
                ft.commit();
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            ex.getLocalizedMessage().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

}

Edit : Added all codes in class.

Thanks nivesh shastri for help.
Here working code :

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password).addOnCompleteListener((Activity) getContext(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment mFrag = new NextFragment();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFrag);
                    ft.commit();
                }
                else {
                    Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                            task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
    });
```

Comment: post your complete class code!

Comment: Added. Thanks for warning.

Comment: find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private void LoginUser(String mail, final String password) {
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password).addOnCompleteListener(getContext(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
 @Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
 if(task.isSuccessful())
 {
 // Do your task in success
 }
else {
 // Do your task in failure

 }
});

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a fragment inside the createUserWithEmailPassword complete listener

**Overview**: Register activity -> Submit button -> createUserWithEmailPassword oncompleteListener -> task successful -> Fragment called

Refer the below code:

```
if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                 //Verify Email Dialog
                  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();                            
                  VerifyEmailDialogFragment verifyFragment = new VerifyEmailDialogFragment();
                  verifyFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Verify Email Dialog");
            }
```

Explanation: Here VerifyEmailDialogFragment  is a dialog fragment which is called when the task of creating the user is successful.

I hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: I think this is for an activity but i'm working on a fragment. All class codes added could you check again ?

Comment: Since the fragment transaction is giving an error try calling the fragment using the approach I mentioned. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you mean use this in an activity and then call fragment. I tried that but app crash when i try to login.

Comment: hey if u are logging in the user u should use signInWithEmailAndPassword and not createUserWithEmailAndPassword because the latter one creates a new account for the user.